# What does this command do, exactly?

Tags: ls

I have this command, but I don't get what it does.

```
ls -Ra | grep -cve/ -e'^\.*$'
```

And how can I do the same with 'find' command.

Comment: Have you read the description of each of the options in the `man` pages?  If so, which ones are you still unclear about?

Comment: What does it exactly mean that I list subdirectories recursively, please?

Comment: It means that `ls` will go into each directory and list the contents of them as well, not just showing the contents of the current directory

Comment: Why is the parameter "-e" twice at the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it into two parts:

```
ls -Ra
```

List all (-a) files recursively (-R). The -a means that files which start with the "." character, which are normally not shown, will be included. The -R means that any subdirectory that ls finds will also be listed, and all subdirectories within those, and so on.

```
grep -cve/ -e'^\.*$'
```

The -c means return the count of mached lines (in this case, the files that "ls" produces), the -v means invert the patterns to search for. There are two patterns: "/" and "^.*$". The first pattern matches lines which have the "/" character in, which is going to be the lines listing the subdirectories. The second pattern matches files whose names are zero-or-more "." characters.

Because the search is inverted, that means that lines that don't match the two patterns are going to be output. And, because the -c option is specified, this will only print the *number* of lines that don't match.

You asked "How can I do the same with the 'find' command?"

The find command won't output a count, so you'd have to pipe it into "wc" like this:

```
find . | wc -l
```

This will include "." however, so you'll end up with an answer one more than the "ls | grep" version.

In a directory on my machine:

```
mmusante$ ls -Ra | grep -cve/ -e'^\.*$'
170594
mmusante$ find . | wc -l
  170595
mmusante$
```

Comment: I have found out that `find . | wc -l` doesn't actually work exactly as the ls command that I write before. I have tried this `find . -name "^\.*$" -prune -o -print | wc -l` but it actually works even without the `-prune` parameter. Do you know why?

Comment: On my system, using the same directory I did in the example `find . -name "\^.*$" -prune -o -print` returns 170595, as does the version without prune. You should be able to use `find .` on its own, but you can try `find . -print` if that doesn't work for you.

The reason why prune has no effect is that you're asking it to prune directory names that contain only the `.` character (i.e. `.` and `..`), which find doesn't use to consider descent anyway.